# How to assign Bulk products to Attributes in an easy way?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, attributes

I had  lots of products in my magento site. I created some few attributes like color, size etc.

**A) Is there any easy of assigning those bulk products to the respective attributes?**

**B) Is that possible to use some SQL queries in phpmyadmin and so can able to assign products to  respective attributes?**

***pls kindly clear me this..***

Comment: I think, you mean you want to assign the attributes to the attribute sets. If that's the case, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15531840/2047249

Comment: @Marius I need to assign BULK products to attributes, suppose i have a product that is of color black, then all the black color products should be assigned to attribute color value black

Comment: See my answer. I hope I understood what you need.

Comment: @Marius Could you please tell how to run your code? should I need to create some blah.php , insert your code and run that php file? If iam wrong, please suggest me..

Comment: @Marius I still had some doubt.. pls dont mind.. what is 85 actually.. 

i will tell my requirement breifly.. Actually for any of my product doesnt have any attribute values before.. SO I need to assign those products with some attribute values..

for every product we will have name, descripion , keywords etc.. So the products having name like '%black%', should be assigned  to color attribute value 'black'

pls try to understand my query.. (I guess iam cleared now!)

Comment: I've updated the answer. I hope this helps now.

Comment: @Marius : Thanx  lot! just small doubt: In the last step, we're assigning products (that're having name like '%black%' ) with color value 'black', right?

Comment: and what is '0' in the last step?

Comment: That's the store Id. 0 means that you set the values for 'default values'

Comment: @Marius : Actually I dont use any stores.. I have 'Default Config' by default.. iam sorry if i said anything wrong.. iam new to magento , if iam wrong , where can I find store id?

Comment: Just use 0 if you don't have any other stores

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! if i get any issues, will let you know! Have a great day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT]**
First look in the database in the table `eav_attribute_option_value` and get the `option_id` for the row with label `Black`. let's say it's `85`.
Now you should get all the products with `black` in the name like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like'=>'%black%'));
$productIds = $collection->getAllIds();
```

Then run this:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($productIds, array('color'=>85), 0)
```

You can use the code above. Just get all the product ids that need to have a specific color.
Also replace `85` with the id of the `Black` option from your color attribute.

Comment: woww! seems like great code, could you please tell me how to run above line of code?

Comment: @JoeyRiver You can create a `blah.php` or you can add it in one of the upgrade scripts in one of your modules.